# eqnarray: redefinition of underscore conflicts with labels containing underscores!

Tags: labels, eqnarray

The underscore redefinition I use for having roman subscripts (see example) is preventing me from defining labels within `eqnarray` environments. How can I solve this? (This problem doesn't appear when I use `align`, but I really need to use `eqnarray` now). Thanks, Jorge.

Example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\catcode`_=\active
\newcommand{_}{\ifmmode\expandafter\sbrm\else\string_\fi}
\newcommand{\sbrm}[1]{\sb{\mathrm{#1}}}

\begin{document}

This compiles:
\begin{align}
    1 \neq 2
\label{my_label_1}
\end{align}

This doesn't:
\begin{eqnarray}
    1 \neq 2
\label{my_label_2}
\end{eqnarray}

\end{document}
```

Compilation error:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \sb 
l.3 ...mathrm  {l}}abel\sb {\mathrm  {2}}}{{2}{1}}
```

Comment: Please expand your snipped into the code for a complete minimal document which produces the error you report. However, my understanding is that use of `eqnarray` is not recommended. Moreover, making `_` active and then using it in labels is a recipe for disaster later, if not sooner. If you simply must do it this way, rename your labels inside these environments, as that's something you can always change. Generally, colons and hyphens are safe here - although not, of course, if you've made them active and turned them into macros.

Comment: Why do you think you need to use `eqnarray`? Why do you need to make `_` active in order to get roman subscripts? (That sounds as if something is seriously screwed up.) Why can't you avoid underscores in labels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first part of the answer you may have figured out already. The first one works because the label is in text mode then `_` is `_`. The second one, on the other hand, is in math mode thus `_` is `\sbrm` and then things go wild. To make sure you can redefine `\label` before loading `amsmath` to make it talk to you:

```
\makeatletter
\def\label#1{%
  \ifmmode
    \typeout{^^JLabel in math mode for \@currenvir^^J}
  \else
    \typeout{^^JLabel in horizontal mode for \@currenvir^^J}
  \fi
  \@bsphack
  \protected@write\@auxout{}%
         {\string\newlabel{#1}{{\@currentlabel}{\thepage}}}%
  \@esphack}
```

the console screen will say:

```
Label in horizontal mode for align

Label in math mode for eqnarray
```

right before throwing an error.

This is because of different implementations. `align` is from `amsmath` so they probably preferred to make the labels while in horizontal mode, while `eqnarray` is from the LaTeX kernel.

Redefining `eqnarray` to make the `\label` in text mode looks like too much. Maybe we can do something with `\label`...

Please, note that I'm just *doing* this, not recommending it!

#### Old solution:

We can make it turn the  `\catcode` of `_` to other, so that we don't use its macro meaning:

```
\def\label{%
  \begingroup
  \catcode`\_=12
  \l@bel}
```

Then we define an inner `\l@bel` that will tokenize the argument and write to the `.aux`:

```
\def\l@bel#1{%
  \@bsphack
  \protected@write\@auxout{}%
         {\string\newlabel{#1}{{\@currentlabel}{\thepage}}}%
  \@esphack
  \endgroup}
```

note that these changes must be done before you load `amsmath` because it stores the current definition of `\label` and you want it to remember the change you made.

#### New solution:

Actually, a more robust approach, would be not to redefine the internal `\label`, but to just patch it with the necessary stuff for the catcode change, because some packages (`hyperref`, I'm looking at you) might erase your definition.

Using `etoolbox` we can devise a solution that is also `hyperref` compatible. We store the old meaning of `\label` in `\old@ltx@label`, then we create the same `\label` wrapper as before, and then we append the `\endgroup` to the `\old@ltx@label`, all of this after the `\begin{document}` (not *at* `\begin{document}`):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AfterEndPreamble{%
  \let\old@ltx@label\label
  \def\label{%
    \begingroup
    \catcode`\_=12
    \old@ltx@label}%
  \apptocmd\old@ltx@label\endgroup{}{}
}
```

I didn't test this solution with other cross-reference packages, though. It might break stuff.

#### Compilable document:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\makeatletter
\def\label{%
  \begingroup
  \catcode`\_=12
  \l@bel}
\def\l@bel#1{%
  \@bsphack
  \protected@write\@auxout{}%
         {\string\newlabel{#1}{{\@currentlabel}{\thepage}}}%
  \@esphack
  \endgroup}
\makeatother

\usepackage{amsmath}

\catcode`_=\active
\newcommand{_}{\ifmmode\expandafter\sbrm\else\string_\fi}
\newcommand{\sbrm}[1]{\sb{\mathrm{#1}}}

\begin{document}

This compiles:
\begin{align}
    1 \neq 2
\label{my_label_1}
\end{align}

This doesn't:
\begin{eqnarray}
    1 \neq 2
\label{my_label_2}
\end{eqnarray}

Now both equation~\eqref{my_label_1} and~\eqref{my_label_2} compile :)

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough reply, Phelype! This totally answers my question.

Answer (score 2):

I consider this just for academic interest, because `eqnarray` should never be used.

You're taking the wrong approach to the problem: since you want the underscore to print as itself in text, the simplest way is to make it math active.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\sbrm}[1]{\sb{\mathrm{#1}}}
\catcode`_=12
\begingroup\lccode`~=`_ \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\sbrm
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`_="8000 }

\begin{document}

This_compiles:
\begin{align}
    1 \neq 2
\label{my_label_1}
\end{align}

This_compiles_too:
\begin{eqnarray}
    1 \neq 2
\label{my_label_2}
\end{eqnarray}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you egreg for your solution and explanation, which greatly helps to clarify the problem. As you point out, my interest in this was rather "academic", as I decided to stay away from eqnarray altogether following everyone's advice :)